# search using radio button

Tags: php, radio-button

I need your help from all of you .

I want to use radio button to search between three different type of keyword and I have a problem with my code now.

This code success on the first and last case only which means case 'Title' and 'email'. The 'description' case doesn't work .

Please help me

this is my code:

```
if ($method=="title"):
$SQL = $SQL . "title LIKE '%$Array[$i]%' "; 
elseif($method=="discription"):
$SQL = $SQL . "discription LIKE '%$Array[$i]%' ";   
else:
$SQL = $SQL . "email LIKE '%$Array[$i]%' ";
endif;
```

and this:

```
if ($cara=="title"):
    $SQL = "SELECT * FROM classified WHERE title LIKE '%$Array[$i]%' "; 
     elseif ($cara=="discription"):
    $SQL = "SELECT * FROM classified WHERE discription LIKE '%$Array[$i]%' ";
     else:
    $SQL = "SELECT * FROM classified WHERE email LIKE '%$Array[$i]%' ";
     endif;
```

the result is:

title http://postimg.org/image/lva7809zz/

description http://postimg.org/image/spp7lj6vj/

note : email work just like title ( i dont have enough reputation to post more than 2 links )

Sorry for my bad English and post.

Comment: In your code, you consistently misspell "description". Possibly the error comes from a mismatch when the $method content is actually spelled correctly?

Comment: `$method == 'discription'` ? perhaps `'description'`? as long as your `radio` value is `description`.

Comment: thank you but it is discription